# Закрытие нового окна в Питоне через Селениум

Tags: python, selenium

есть вопрос, как мне закрыть это окно:

[image]

Нажимаю на сайте на кнопку появлется такое окно, мне надо его закрыть, как это можно сделать в Селениуме

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал на примере другого сайта, но суть одинакова: переключаться на новое открытое окно и закрывать через `.close`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

o = Options()
o.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=o)

driver.get('https://www.livesport.com/ru/basketball/usa/nba/#/4CS5kbsl/table/overall')
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'onetrust-accept-btn-handler').click() # Закрытие cookie
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'event__part--4').click() # Клик по кнопке и открытие нового окна 

windows = driver.window_handles # Поиск всех окон 
driver.switch_to.window(windows[-1]) # Переключение на последнее из тех, что открылось
driver.close() # Закрытие окна
```